# Snaps refresh not finding 'teams' on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: snap

I'm struggling to refresh MS Teams snap, like this:-

```
$ sudo snap install teams
snap "teams" is already installed, see 'snap help refresh'

$ sudo snap refresh teams
error: snap "teams" not found
```

I'd like to know how to resolve this but ultimately I need to try a beta version since there appears to be a bug in teams that causes the pop-up for creating a new meeting to be misformatted, but I get a similar error:

```
$ sudo snap refresh teams --channel=beta
error: snap "teams" not found
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

In this case Microsoft have discontinued the application, so there will be no more updates to that snap.

In general however, when this error occurs, it's usually not your system at fault, this is a problem with the snap or the store. In this example, the snap is visible from the [store page](https://snapcraft.io/teams), but is not visible from the graphical Ubuntu Software store, nor from the command line.

```bash
snap info teams
error: no snap found for "teams"
```

If you had a snap installed, and the publisher subsequently discontinues or abandons it, this will happen.

Comment: Thanks popey for your answer, I will try with snapcraft forum.

Comment: I thought it would be useful to copy the surprising response from the snapcraft forum:

MS Teams’ desktop app for Linux is deprecated and they no longer provide it in any form, snap or otherwise. Official advice is to use the web app instead, including by possibly setting it as a Progressive Web App to look more native.